# Unable to open file, error code = 0x80070002 Visual Studio error. I'm not sure how to fix this

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

Currently doing a school project using Visual Studio and C++. I can't seem to compile and test my code because I keep getting a Visual Studio pop up that reads

> Error: Unable to open file U:\ProjectOne\Debug\Source.obj. Error Code = 0x80070002.

I'm not entirely sure how to go about this as I am still new to programming and have no idea how file management works yet. The only files I am using thus far are a Source.cpp file and a Header.h file in my project folder.

Comment: In Visual Studio, under the "Tools Menu", there is a little utility named "Error Lookup".  Run it and type in the error code you see there, and you will get back the message "The system cannot find the file specified".  That sounds to me like your file path is wrong

Comment: @Joe how would I go about fixing the file path?

Comment: 1. Find the function call in your program that causes this error be generated.  2.  Stop the application in the debugger at that point and examine the value of the string path you are supplying to the function.  3. Go to Windows Explorer and see what's truly there.  From that you should be able to figure out what you did wrong.

Comment: Try doing a clean build.

Comment: @Joe, the error is when trying to BUILD, not run.

Comment: @ChrisMM how would I go about doing a clean build and what exactly does this help with?

Comment: ***and what exactly does this help with?*** Perhaps the mentioned .obj file was corrupted on your disk.  A build clean causes it to be deleted so that it will be rebuilt on the next build.

Comment: This error also could be caused by your antivirus.

Comment: Is Visual Studio able to run a simple hello world program?